# Resolving open generic with Autofac and MEF integration

Tags: dependency-injection, mef, autofac

I have a web application that I'm bootstrapping with Autofac and dependencies from common libraries are injected into controllers filters etc.  Some of these dependencies are open generics and this all works fine.

In my web bootstrapper I'm doing it like this;

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(OpenGeneric<>)).As(typeof(IOpenGeneric<>));
```

I now need to create an application that will be extensible (via plugins) that will consume some of these same dependencies.  I'm using MEF for composing the application and extension discovery and hooking it up to Autofac using the Autofac.Integration.Mef nuget package:

```
builder.RegisterComposablePartCatalog(catalog);
```

I'm finding that my dependencies are not being injected when they are the generic dependencies (other interfaces and concrete types are fine) unless I explicitly supply the generic type like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<OpenGeneric<User>>().As<IOpenGeneric<User>>().Exported(x => x.As<IOpenGeneric<User>>());
```

I would really rather not have to supply each type that fulfils the constraint.

Is it possible to do this?
I understand that MEF itself does not support open generics but I thought this would be possible using the Autofac integration.

Comment: I haven't found a way around this but have decided that my plugins will take an Autofac ILifetimeScope instead and will resolve their dependencies themselves - it actually works out better for the lifetime management that I need for these plugins

Comment: How did you registered the ILifetimeScope for export?

Comment: I configured Autofac & MEF to supply an ILifetimeScope by exporting it back to MEF. This way, any of my plugins that require an ILifetimeScope receive a new one and the lifetime of my dependencies are bound to the scope: builder.Register(x => _container.BeginLifetimeScope()).As<ILifetimeScope>().Exported(x => x.As<ILifetimeScope>());